# Pygettext - Gettext over multiple lines

Tags: python, gettext

I want to translate a string with PyGettext. The problems is, the string is very long. So I had to split it into multiple lines:

```
print _("Some text... foo bar foo bar foo bar ..... blah blah" + \
        "More text")
```

But I get the following error message:

```
*** ../myApp:1: Seen unexpected token "+"
```

How can I write a string like that? I don't want to write it in one line because the code will look terrible. I also don't want to use three quotation marks (""") because the translation will be messed up with a way too many spaces....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python compiler concatenates adjacent string literals.

```
print _("Some text... foo bar foo bar foo bar ..... blah blah"
        "More text")
```

...

```
>>> print 'a' 'b'
ab
```

Comment: What's that underscore?

Comment: @MxyL: That would be `gettext.gettext`.

Comment: @MxyL Yes, it is: _ = gettext.translation("myApp").ugettext